# Haystack foo_field__in lockup bugs.

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

```
s = ['keyword', 'search phrase', 'synonym']  # simple array
```

**This code return nothing**  Returns empty array

```
 SearchQuerySet().models(Expert).filter(foo__in=s)
```

**This works, why?** Returns normal result, as for searching 1st element

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Expert).filter(foo__in=s[0])
#EQUALS
SearchQuerySet().models(Expert).filter(foo=s[0])
```

Comment: Its MultiValueField. Same with FacetMultiValueField